# sudo.Sudid Error: BadOrigin on polkadotjs

Tags: substrate-node-template, substrate-node

I am adding asset pallet to the runtime. When I try to interact with it with `sudo > asset > create`, I got `error: BadOrigin` issue. Can someone please help me why I am getting this issue.

I found this in [stackexchange](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1941/sudobridgerococograndpa-setowner-call-resulting-in-badorigin-error) but it doesn't help me.

I also try with not-root account but it didn't help.

I have posted error image link [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PzSdA9YIc7QHEjtZPRw6nhOt5Y3KLabW/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It requires `CreateOrigin`. https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/c7d26dcf3d6c19fa7dcbd1f2633e337e5a5cbc40/frame/assets/src/lib.rs#L601

And the default configuration is not `EnsureRoot` if you are using the template. https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/c7d26dcf3d6c19fa7dcbd1f2633e337e5a5cbc40/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L1488

Please check what you have configured to the `CreateOrigin` and use the proper origin from the PolkadotJS.

Comment: `type CreateOrigin = AsEnsureOriginWithArg<EnsureSigned<AccountId>>;` I have configured this @AurevoirXavier.

Comment: which means origin is `ALICE` isn't it?

Comment: Or should I set origin manually?